# Script for launching Firefox with N tabs of specific sites?

Tags: firefox, script, arch-linux, macros, i3-window-manager

I'm an i3 on ArchLinux user, and for my workflow I typically like to launch a specific set of tabs in one Firefox window, in one i3 workspace, and then launch a separate window instance in a separate instance with another set of specific tabs (URLs).

Are there any utilities or can I script something up so I can launch these two windows in these two workspaces, with a set of specific tabs/URLs?